# Early 90's children's book about a girl who travelled back in time

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, childrens-novel

I remember this book I loved in the early-mid 90's about a girl who was able to travel back in time to the 70's and meet her mum (I think). I can't remember the whole story, but I feel like maybe her parents were deceased in the present. 
The other bits and pieces I can recall...

- She had a crush in the present day, and it turned out that his grandfather was the cause of someone's death in the 70's... and by figuring this out when she travelled back in time, she caused the grandfather's arrest, meaning her present-day crush was never born.
- There was definitely some subplot regarding a cryogenics lab.
- There was a girl in the present day who had "cookie" eyes (maybe they were like cookies with bites taken out of them?), and she never knew her parents, and would frequent a hologram-virtual-reality place in the mall and make-up fantasy picnics and such with her "real" family... In the end, after the past was altered, this girl ended up in the "new" present day with her family rather than being an orphan.
- There was definitely a party that took place on a beach.
- The kids in the present day were all part of some study dealing with mind-control and being able to make objects move without touching them. Somehow this factored in to the lead female being able to time travel.

Comment: If "Whispers from the Grave" is the correct book, do yourself a favour and answer this question!

Comment: I have flagged this question for delete. The OP has either answered the question, by editing the question, or not.  In either case any answer from now on would be opinion based.  The OP does not have a continuing history on SE.

Comment: @JamesJenkins - Wouldn't it be better to edit out the resolution from the question and re-post it as a proper answer. As a community wiki perhaps?

Comment: @SystemDown, why?  There are no up votes on the question. Other then providing spam for the book, there are no redeaming qualities for the question.

Comment: @JamesJenkins- Why keep any question open? In the hope that it might help someone else in the future. Now I know that there's a whole big debate on whether identify-this style questions have any future value, but since ScFi&F already allows identify questions we may as well treat this question like the rest and keep it open.

Answer (score 5):

Per the answer in the original post, the book in question is "[*Whispers From the Grave*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/594810.Whispers_from_the_Grave)" by Leslie Rule

[image: Whispers from the Grave]

> When Jenna discovers the diary of a girl who was murdered over 100 years ago, she is startled by how much they have in common. Rita looked like her, acted like her, and faced the trials of high school while experiencing the thrill of first love. As Jenna reads of Rita's tragic past, she fears for her own future. Because Rita's history is repeating itself--in Jenna's life.